# Sns Heatmap save as png jpeg image with full labels visible via python

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to save my heat map in png format using the below code, but the labels are getting trimmed when I am saving the heatmap. Please help to keep the labels inside the figure.

```
    array = confusion_matrix(gts, preds, labels=class_name)
    #print(gts)
    #print(preds)
    df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, index = class_name, columns = class_name)
    print("Confusion Matrix")
    print(df_cm)
    plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))

    sns_plot = sns.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, cmap =sns.cm.rocket_r,linecolor='white', linewidths=1)

    results_path = 'results.png'
    #print(results_path)
    plt.savefig(results_path, dpi=400)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding plt.tight_layout() after sns.heatmap? Usually this solves the trimming of labels.

Answer (score 1):

```py
results_path = 'results.png'
#print(results_path)
plt.savefig(results_path)
```

Comment: When I export the image to a png file. The labels on x,y axes, title of the plot are black in color. So when viewed with photos app in win, the text is not visible. Is there any way to export with white color text?